# Why is my json-encoded object nil in Swift

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

[My swift code is close to the one found on this site by Jameson Quave.](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/)

In serial if I println(json) the value is nil. However if I println(data), I get numbers. If I `println("Body: \(strData)")` I get the following. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is sample data:

```
Body: Optional([
{
    "LocAddress": "2045 Broadway ",
    "City": "New York",
    "Region": "New York",
    "Country": "United States"
},
{
    "LocAddress": "6916 4th Ave",
    "City": "New York",
    "Region": "New York",
    "Country": "United States"
},
{
    "LocAddress": "Bleaker St.",
    "City": "New York",
    "Region": "New York",
    "Country": "United States"
},
{
    "LocAddress": "37-45 87th St",
    "City": "New York",
    "Region": "New York",
    "Country": "United States"
},
{
    "LocAddress": "88-35 249th St",
    "City": "New York",
    "Region": "New York",
    "Country": "United States"
},
{
    "LocAddress": "225 West 79th",
    "City": "New York",
    "Region": "New York",
    "Country": "United States"
}
```

])

I apologize if this question has been asked. I am a frequent user to stackoverflow and did my best trying to find an answer before resorting to posting this question.

Comment: If you look at the link I sent, see where there is a statement println("Body: \(strData)"). 'Body: ' part comes from there and Optional() is from swift compiler. I could simply add a ! mark at the end of line var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! and it would take care of optional. Regardless of those two things, my strData is in JSON format, so why is it that when I do  var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary and then println(json), is it nil?

Comment: What you have is a JSON *array* and not a *dictionary*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data is not valid JSON.  It Looks like it might be JSONP, regardless, if you get rid of the opening `Body: Optional(` and closing `)` You'd have valid JSON.  However that JSON, as indicated by square brackets, is an array, and you are optionally casting it to a dictionary.

You might try casting it to an NSArray first, or an [[String:String]] that is Array of String String dictionaries.  If you go the NSArray route, you can then iterate the array and cast the members to NSDictionaries.

Comment: I don't think I am casting the NSString strData to NSDictionary, I am converting data which is a bunch of numbers <6b222c0a 20202020 20202020 22526567 696f6e22 3a20224e 65772059 6f726b22 2c0a2020 20202020 20202243 6f756e74 7279223a 2022556e 69746564 20537461 74657322 0a202020 207d0a5d>

Comment: from your comment `var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary` this is deserializing the string and casting it to a dictionary.  Instead you need to do  `var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSArray`

Comment: I think this worked, just one more thing: how can I iterate through this array. Sorry for asking such simple questions but my brain is half dead. I cant access any members by simply doing json[0]............................................ NVM I was removed the ? and it worked

Comment: For dict in json as! [NSDictionary] { println(dict["city"])}. Sorry on mobile.

Comment: no problem, I just accepted your answer. You sir are a godsent! Thank you very much. I have been stressing over this for the past two hours